# Is it possible to derive the Doppler effect formulas for sound using relative velocity?

Tags: reference-frames, observers, relative-motion, doppler-effect

Is it possible to derive the [Doppler effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect) formulas for sound using relative velocity? If possible can anyone please explain it to me.

Comment: What do you mean with "building" the Doppler effect formulae "using relative velocity"? Are you asking about how to derive the Doppler equations?

Comment: yes @ACuriousMind

Comment: As far as I know Doppler effect formula is already derived from relative velocity to two observer. can you be more specific?

Comment: Do you mean the relativistic doppler effect with light, or the classical one with sound? If you're using sound, the velocity of the medium must be considered.